# Why is Xcode complaining about "unrecognized selector sent to instance" error?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode6

let me start off by saying I know what the error means. It's basically saying the Selector method was invoked on an object that doesn't have that method.

Anyways, here's my Tile.h header file:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Weapon.h"
#import "Armor.h"


@interface Tile : NSObject

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *story;
@property (strong, nonatomic) Weapon *weapon;
@property (strong, nonatomic) Armor *armor;
@property (nonatomic) int healthEffect;

@end
```

Here is my Factory.h header file:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


@interface Factory : NSObject

- (NSArray *)tiles;

@end
```

And here is my Factory.m file:

```
#import "Factory.h"
#import "Tile.h"

@implementation Factory

- (NSArray *) tiles
{
    Tile *tile7 = [ [Tile alloc] init];
    tile7.story = @"blah blah";
    tile7.healthEffect = 8;
}
@end
```

Some code is excluded in the Factory.m file because they're trivial but if I try to compile and run, I get this error:

```
2014-10-29 17:26:27.944 Pirate Adventure[718:15257]
-[Tile setHealthEffect:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7b03b8e0
2014-10-29 17:26:27.946 Pirate Adventure[718:15257] *** Terminating app due to uncaught 
exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Tile setHealthEffect:]: unrecognized 
selector sent to instance 0x7b03b8e0'
```

It's complaining when I try to set tile7.healthEffect = 8;

I don't even understand why it's complaining about the setHealthEffect method, I don't even have that define in my Tile.h header file. Also, healthEffect is just a property of the tile object, so I should be able to set it to whatever integer value I want without having to define a method to set the value right?

I'm confused.

Thanks!

Added Tile.m file:

```
#import "Tile.h"

@implementation Tile

@synthesize healthEffect = _healthEffect;

@end
```

Comment: Just a little question when I look at your `tiles` method. You specified a return type of `NSArray *` but have no return statement in the actual implementation. For us to give you an answer, you might need to edit the post to include the code where you actually set the healthEffect

Comment: yah sorry about that, I did return the tiles array, just didn't include it in there

Comment: I recreated your situation, but my code works fine using the same methods/implementations/classes you provided. May the error possibly be cause from a different line than `tile7.healthEffect = 8`? If not, the error is caused by code you failed to include. I would also check for interfering polymorphism or multiple declarations of tile7, based on the possibility of the error message telling you that the method is called by a class not an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

```
tile7.healthEffect = 8;
```

is just syntactic shugar for

```
[tile7 setHealthEffect: 8];
```

If you have a @property declaration in a class, the compiler will normally automatically generate a setter setHealthEffect and a getter healthEffect as well as an instance variable _healthEffect for you unless you create them yourself.

I suspect your problem is in Tile.m. Can you share this as well?

Comment: Yeah, for some reason the setter has not been generated.  I've lost track of when it is and isn't automatically generated anymore, since they've changed the rules so many times.  But likely the OP has an `@synthesize` for `healthEffect` that is upsetting the applecart.

Answer (score 0):

The problem does not rest in the code you've shared with us thus far. For some reason, your setter simply hasn't been synthesized. Please share your `Tile` implementation. For example, you'd get this sort of error if either:

- the `healthEffect` was a property declared in a protocol used by `Tile` class; or
- your `Tile` implementation had a line that explicitly declared that the property shouldn't be synthesized:

  ```
  @dynamic heathEffect;
  ```

You go on to ask:

For some reason, your setter simply hasn't been synthesized.

> I don't even understand why it's complaining about the `setHealthEffect` method, I don't even have that define in my Tile.h header file.

As Klaus pointed out, using `tiles.healthEffect = ...` is equivalent to calling `setHealthEffect`.

> Also, `healthEffect` is just a property of the tile object, so I should be able to set it to whatever integer value I want without having to define a method to set the value right?

Correct. This `setHealthEffect` method should have been synthesized for you automatically. Since Xcode version 4.4, these setters have been synthesized for us. There's nothing in your question to suggest why this setter was not synthesized for you in this case.

Comment: updated my post, there's nothing in my Tile.m file. The code did not auto synthesized for me. The weird thing is I also have another file that takes another nonatomic property integer variable, and that works fine without synthesize

Comment: Hard to guess without seeing more, as there's nothing here that would suggest why it's not getting automatically synthesized for you. A couple of final suggestions: 1. Try purging the "derived data" folder and restarting Xcode and make sure there isn't some weird state issue. 2. Try recreating the [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) problem you describe, because until we can reproduce it, it's impossible to fix it. I'm unable to reproduce the behavior you describe.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Rob. I will try some things and get back to you.

Comment: Hello Rob, I updated my Tile.m file to include only the code "@synthesize healthEffect = _healthEffect" and it works. I still don't understand why though??

Comment: Not leaping out at me, either. Automatic synthesis happens in Xcode 4.4 and later unless you use `@dynamic` or the property is inherited from protocol. But neither of those appear to be in play in your example. Again, I can't help you until you show us reproducible example. If you create test project with just code in your question, the problem does not manifest itself. It's got to be something else in the project.